# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Notification - Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Warning

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I keep getting the following messages. But there is nothing in my `nginx` logs which indicates that requests were returned with status `5xx`. Also, app seems to working as expected. Any pointers why I might be getting these?

Message:

> Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Warning. 50.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx. Insufficient request rate (12.0 requests/min) to determine application health. 1 out of 2 instances are impacted. See instance health for details.

eb logs show the following events around the same time. And they look like a hack attempt. My guess is that these POST requests failure are making EB think that instances are unhealthy. Any advise, how can we prevent this ? Thanks.

```
2019/02/10 23:49:37 [error] 3263#0: *23308 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.31.35.221, server: , request: "POST /51314.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:80/51314.php", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

2019/02/10 23:49:37 [error] 3263#0: *23308 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.31.35.221, server: , request: "POST /fusheng.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:80/fusheng.php", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

2019/02/10 23:49:38 [error] 3263#0: *23308 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.31.35.221, server: , request: "POST /repeat.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:80/repeat.php", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

2019/02/10 23:49:39 [error] 3263#0: *23308 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.31.35.221, server: , request: "POST /api.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:80/api.php", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

2019/02/10 23:49:40 [error] 3263#0: *23308 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.31.35.221, server: , request: "POST /xiaodai.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:80/xiaodai.php", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

2019/02/10 23:49:40 [error] 3263#0: *23308 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.31.35.221, server: , request: "POST /xiaodai.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:80/xiaodai.php", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Example reasons can be

- **nginx proxy** crashed on the instance
- high **CPU** usage on the instance
- high **memory** usage on the instance
- **deployment failure** on the instance

Comment: Sorry. probably should have mentioned in the original post. None of these are the reasons. I have checked. Thanks.